# Implementation ideas for software defined radios

Tags: radio, gsm, software-defined-radio

I find [Software defined radios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio) interesting, and was searching for ways to learn about it.

One way is getting your feet wet with devices like [USRP products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Software_Radio_Peripheral).

However, USRPs are rather expensive.

What are alternatives/less expensive suggestions for getting a software-defined-radio implementation?

I would like to use it to eventually build things like a GSM base transceiver station, etc. in a budget-friendly way.

Comment: Please define "budget-friendly".

Comment: Budget friendly like less than $100

Comment: Then you'll have to wait a few years. Right now even the "revolutionary" [Per Vices Phi](http://www.pervices.com/support.html) is $750.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use for this purpose cheap USB TV tuner. I've read that ppl have good results with it. Here is the link:

http://hackaday.com/2012/03/30/working-software-defined-radio-with-a-tv-tuner-card/

Obviously it is viable only for receiving (so no, it is not possible to make GSM base station with it).

However GPS receiver is doable:

http://hackaday.com/2012/04/13/those-usb-tv-tuners-used-for-sdr-can-also-grab-gps-data/

Comment: tnx, but any ideas for sdr devices tht can do tx also?